# Access web service behind jump host via ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have created a web service running on protected server(Centos, `123.123.123.123:8192`), we can only login to the web server via SSH from a jump server (say `111.111.111.111`). I can login the web server via SSH (first login to jump server, then dump to web server). Now I want to make a HTTP request to web server, How do setup the SSH tunnel to make it worker? Or if current limitation impossible, what is most secure way to open a door to make it possible?

Other limitations:

- the web server can only access to database, other out data are disabled (no `yum`, no `ping`, e.t.,)
- the jump server's SSH server listen on redefined port, say 32220.
- the user name of web server (`ws`) and jump server (`js`) are different.

Answer (score 10):

```
ssh -L 8192:192.0.2.3:8192 198.51.100.7
```

then access `http://localhost:8192/`

What this does is:

`-L` = Listen on a local port (where the ssh client is running)

`8192` = Listen on port 8192

`192.0.2.3:8192` = When a connection comes in to 8192 to the ssh client, forward that across the SSH tunnel and connect out to 192.0.2.3:8192

`198.51.100.7` is the normal "server you want to ssh to"

Comment: not sure if the jump server is able to reach directly 123.123.123.123:8192
OP did not specified it

Comment: This works perfectly when you need to access webservices and ports locally